# How to make a table of $\sum_{i=1}^n$?

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation, latex

I want to create a table of $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n i^k$ for $1\le  k\le 5$. The output I want to obtain is a `TeXForm` output as follows.

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n i &=\frac1 2 n(n-1)\\
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 &=\frac1 2 n(n-1)(2n+1)\\
&\vdots
\end{align}

My attempt is as follows but it does not produce what I want to achieve.

```
Sum[i^k, {i, 1, n}] // Table[Factor[#], {k, 1, 5}] & // TableForm
```

Comment: Do you want to generate LaTeX code or do you just want to format this on screen?  The latter is easier.

Comment: @Szabolcs: First priority is to produce the LaTeX output, but it will be nice if the on-screen output is also provided.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a way that I find clear:

Make sure `i` and `n` have no value: `i=.; n=.`.

Generate a list of the held sum expressions, taking care to make the exponent go away from $i^1$.

```
list = Table[With[{e = i^k}, HoldForm[Sum[e, {i, 1, n}]]], {k, 5}]
```

Use `ReleaseHold` to make a table of results:

```
TeXForm@TableForm[# == ReleaseHold[#] & /@ list]
```

$$
\begin{array}{c}
 \sum _{i=1}^n i=\frac{1}{2} n (n+1) \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^3=\frac{1}{4} n^2 (n+1)^2 \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^4=\frac{1}{30} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \left(3 n^2+3 n-1\right) \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^5=\frac{1}{12} n^2 (n+1)^2 \left(2 n^2+2 n-1\right) \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: This method (using `With`), as written, has a disadvantage in that a global value of `i` will be substituted if it exists.  The same is true of `n` in both our methods but I cleared `n` beforehand to address that.

Comment: I realize it's not a matter of `With`, so I wonder, why use `e = i^k` rather than `e = k` and `i^e`?

Comment: Gah, can't read today.  Now I see why you did that, and +1.  However, consider wrapping everything in `Block[{i, n}, ...]` IMHO.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a start (adjusted based on Szabolcs's statement that `Row` and `TeXForm` don't work together in v9):

```
Clear[n]

# == ReleaseHold[#] & /@
   Array[HoldForm[Sum[i^#, {i, 1, n}]] &, 5] // Column // TeXForm
```

$\begin{array}{l}
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^1=\frac{1}{2} n (n+1) \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^3=\frac{1}{4} n^2 (n+1)^2 \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^4=\frac{1}{30} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \left(3 n^2+3 n-1\right) \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^5=\frac{1}{12} n^2 (n+1)^2 \left(2 n^2+2 n-1\right)
\end{array}$

The two `Function` expressions could have been combined, but I felt that this was easier to read and easier to adjust.

Edit: I note that Szabolcs's answer shows the values above and below the Sigma symbols.  Apparently that is a version difference, as I am using version 7 and his code produces the same output as mine in this regard.

Comment: Are you using version 7?  When I try to apply TeXForm to any kind of `Row` expression in v9, I get an error `"TeXForm of \!\(TemplateSlotSequence[1, \"\"]\) is not supported."`  I thought it must have worked before ..

Comment: @Szabolcs Strange; yes, I am.  So the solution is to put `TeXForm` inside?

Comment: @Szabolcs No, that doesn't work either.  Do you mind if I copy your method to my answer?

Comment: Okay, go ahead.  There seems to be a bug in v9 with Row and TeXForm.  Can't use them together.

Answer (score 8):

```
TableForm[Table[{
   HoldForm[Sum[i^z, {i, 1, n}]] /. z -> k, "=",
   Factor[Sum[i^k, {i, 1, n}]]},
  {k, 1, 5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Won't adding `// TeXForm` at the end make it TeXForm?

Comment: @RunnyKine - not on version 7

Comment: Ah, I see. It works on Version 9.

Answer (score 8):

In Version 10, we can use `Inactivate` and `Activate` to achieve this easily:

```
With[{rl = Array[{m -> #} &, 5], s = Inactivate[Sum[i^m, {i, 1, n}], Sum]}, 
   Thread[Equal[s /. rl, Factor[Activate[s] /. rl]]]] // Column // TeXForm
```

\begin{array}{l}
 \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}i=\frac{1}{2} n (n+1) \\
 \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}i^2=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \\
 \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}i^3=\frac{1}{4} n^2 (n+1)^2 \\
 \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}i^4=\frac{1}{30} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \left(3 n^2+3 n-1\right)
   \\
 \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}i^5=\frac{1}{12} n^2 (n+1)^2 \left(2 n^2+2 n-1\right) \\
\end{array}

Note that this also does not give the undesired `i^1`

Comment: The generated output `\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}` is too complicated.

Answer (score 5):

Another entry:

```
With[{rule = Array[{m -> #} &, 5], sm = HoldForm@Sum[i^m, {i, 1, n}]},
Thread[Equal[sm /. rule, Factor[ReleaseHold@sm /. rule]]]] // Column // TeXForm
```

\begin{array}{l}
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^1=\frac{1}{2} n (n+1) \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^3=\frac{1}{4} n^2 (n+1)^2 \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^4=\frac{1}{30} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \left(3 n^2+3 n-1\right) \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^5=\frac{1}{12} n^2 (n+1)^2 \left(2 n^2+2 n-1\right) \\
\end{array}

Or to get rid of the `1` in `i^1`

```
With[{hd = Join[{HoldForm@Sum[i, {i, 1, n}]}, HoldForm@Sum[i^m, {i, 1, n}] /. Table[{m -> j},
 {j, 2, 5}]], sm = Factor[Sum[i^m, {i, 1, n}] /. Array[{m -> #} &, 5]]}, 
 Thread[Equal[hd, sm]]] // Column // TeXForm
```

\begin{array}{l}
 \sum _{i=1}^n i=\frac{1}{2} n (n+1) \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^3=\frac{1}{4} n^2 (n+1)^2 \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^4=\frac{1}{30} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \left(3 n^2+3 n-1\right) \\
 \sum _{i=1}^n i^5=\frac{1}{12} n^2 (n+1)^2 \left(2 n^2+2 n-1\right) \\
\end{array}