# Incompatibility of Row and TeXForm

Tags: bugs, output-formatting, warning-messages, latex, conversion

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and persisting through 11.0**

---

***Update:*** Since no one has been able to give a reason for this change in behavior or provide a solution I am tagging this as a bug.  Please report it to Wolfram Support if this affects your use of *Mathematica*.

---

In *Mathematica* 7 `Row` and `TeXForm` work harmoniously:

```
{x^a, Sqrt@b, ArcSin[c]} // Row // TeXForm
```

> ```
> x^a\sqrt{b}\sin ^{-1}(c)
> ```

As LaTeX:

> $x^a\sqrt{b}\sin ^{-1}(c)$

Unfortunately this is broken in more recent versions.  *Mathematica* 10 returns:

> TeXForm::unspt: TeXForm of TemplateSlotSequence[1,] is not supported. >>

This error was [reported](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40424/how-to-make-a-table-of-sum-i-1n/40425#comment121006_40425) in version 9 as well.

An attempt at a workaround is to substitute `Grid` for `Row` but the LaTeX code generated is different:

```
{{x^a, Sqrt@b, ArcSin[c]}} // Grid // TeXForm
```

[image]

And it formats differently:

> $\begin{array}{ccc} x^a & \sqrt{b} & \sin ^{-1}(c) \\ \end{array}$

The [documentation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bdpcg4xu-cycfzl) for `TeXForm` indicates that it is extensible with rules for `Format` but I could not find a rule that worked.  While I can manually convert a single Row as follows:

```
StringJoin[ToString /@ TeXForm /@ {x^a, Sqrt@b, ArcSin[c]}]
```

> ```
> x^a\sqrt{b}\sin ^{-1}(c)
> ```

(Though note that one must copy as **Plain Text**.)

However attempting to make this a `Format` rule results in double-conversion and I get this:

[image]

---

#### Is this indeed a bug as I believe?

#### What is the best work-around for the problem, preferably automatic?

Comment: does this help (TeXForm /@ {x^a, Sqrt@b, ArcSin[c]}) // Row

Comment: @Algohi Thanks, but not really.  This is similar to my own attempt near the bottom and it still doesn't allow for automatic conversion where `Row` is part of a larger expression.

Comment: So have you reported it again Mr.W?

Comment: @Jacob No I have not.  I was waiting to see what others had to say about this.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard I usually use `RowBox` and `DisplayForm` to get LaTex code from MM. I don't know if it works in MM10, since I don't have one. `TeXForm /@ {x^a, Sqrt@b, ArcSin[c]} // RowBox // DisplayForm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

The TLDR answer is:

```
System`Convert`CommonDump`templateBoxToDisplay = BoxForm`TemplateBoxToDisplayBoxes
```

A more long-winded answer follows.

**Background**

The basic approach used by [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) is to create [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes, and then to convert those boxes into a [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) string. The basic internal function that [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) uses to convert boxes into a string is `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex ``. For example, consider `BesselJ[n, x]`. The [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes are:

```
MakeBoxes[BesselJ[n, x], TraditionalForm]
```

> TemplateBox[{"n", "x"}, "BesselJ"]

Notice how `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex `` is used to convert the above boxes into a string:

```
TracePrint[
    ToString[BesselJ[n, x], TeXForm],
    _System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex,
    TraceInternal->True
]
```

> System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[TemplateBox[{n,x},BesselJ]]
>
> System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[RowBox[{SubscriptBox[J,n],(,x,)}]]
>
> ...
>
> "J_n(x)"

By default, `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex `` uses `` System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes `` to convert [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) objects into normal boxes:

```
TracePrint[
    System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[TemplateBox[{"n","x"},"BesselJ"]],
    _System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes
]
```

> System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes[TemplateBox[{n,x},BesselJ]]
>
> System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes[TemplateBox[{n,x},BesselJ],Display]
>
> "J_n(x)"

and:

```
System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes[TemplateBox[{"n","x"},"BesselJ"]]
```

> RowBox[{SubscriptBox["J", "n"], "(", "x", ")"}]

Summarizing, [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) does the following:

1. Create [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes
2. Convert [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) objects into normal boxes
3. Convert normal boxes into a [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) string

**The problem with Row**

So, where do things go wrong with [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) objects? In Mathematica version 7 and earlier, [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) objects were formatted as [`RowBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RowBox) objects directly, and so there was no need to convert [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) objects into normal boxes. However, starting in versions 8 or 9, [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) objects were formatted as [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) objects. For example, in M9 (I don't have ready access to earlier versions):

```
MakeBoxes[Row[{x, y}], TraditionalForm]
```

> TemplateBox[{"x", "y"}, "RowDefault"]

One possible fix for this issue is to restore the old functionality of formatting [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) objects as normal boxes, and this is what the global variable `` BoxForm`$UseTemplateSlotSequenceForRow `` controls. I don't like this solution, as it means that [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) objects will never use [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox), which I think is a shame (I think [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) offers both speed and memory advantages). Also, it only fixes one symptom of the issue, and not the underlying problem. So, let's figure out the underlying problem.

**TemplateSlotSequence**

Here is the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) format for a [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) object:

```
boxes = MakeBoxes[Row[{x, y}, None], TraditionalForm]
```

> TemplateBox[{"x", "y"}, "RowNoSeparators"]

*(I used a [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) object with a separator for reasons I will explain later)*. These are the normal boxes that [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) creates for this [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox):

```
System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes[
    TemplateBox[{"x","y"}, "RowNoSeparators"]
]
```

> RowBox[{TemplateSlotSequence[1]}]

Notice the appearance of a [`TemplateSlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateSlotSequence) object. This kind of object is not supported by `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex ``. Also, just like other [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot) objects, the [`TemplateSlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateSlotSequence) object only has meaning when it is inside of a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function) object, so the above output is not a valid form of normal boxes. This is the reason for the error that gets reported:

```
ToString[Row[{x, y}, None], TeXForm]
```

> TeXForm::unspt: TeXForm of TemplateSlotSequence[1] is not supported.
>
> ""

*Single argument Row*

The above error doesn't happen for single argument [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) because `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex `` was hacked to support it. Compare:

```
TracePrint[
    System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[TemplateBox[{"x", "y"}, "RowNoSeparators"]],
    _System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes
]
```

> System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes[TemplateBox[{x,y},RowNoSeparators]]
>
> System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes[TemplateBox[{x,y},RowNoSeparators],Display]
>
> TeXForm::unspt: TeXForm of TemplateSlotSequence[1] is not supported.
>
> ""

with:

```
TracePrint[
    System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[TemplateBox[{"x", "y"}, "RowDefault"]],
    _System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes
]
```

> "xy"

Notice that the "RowDefault" [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) never gets processed by `` System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes `` because `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex `` has a special [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) for this case.

**Non-Row TemplateSlotSequence issues**

The failure to support [`TemplateSlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateSlotSequence) is not restricted to [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) objects. For example:

```
ToString[BellY[a, b, {c, d}], TeXForm]
```

> TeXForm::unspt: TeXForm of TemplateSlotSequence[3,,] is not supported.
>
> "Y_{a,b}()"

```
ToString[WignerD[{j, m1, m2}, \[Theta]], TeXForm]
```

> TeXForm::unspt: TeXForm of TemplateSlotSequence[4,,] is not supported.
>
> "D_{\text{m1},\text{m2}}^j()"

So, changing the formatting of [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) so that it doesn't use a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) is not really sufficient, it won't fix the above errors.

**Fix**

The function used by [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) to convert [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) objects into normal boxes is `` System`Convert`CommonDump`templateBoxToDisplay ``:

```
TracePrint[
    System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes[TemplateBox[{"x", "y"}, "RowNoSeparators"]],
    _System`Convert`CommonDump`templateBoxToDisplay,
    TraceInternal->True
]
```

> System`Convert`CommonDump`templateBoxToDisplay[TemplateBox[{x,y},RowNoSeparators]]
>
> RowBox[{TemplateSlotSequence[1]}]

Instead of using `` System`Convert`CommonDump`templateBoxToDisplay `` one could use `` BoxForm`TemplateBoxToDisplayBoxes ``:

```
template = TemplateBox[{"x","y"},"RowNoSeparators"];

System`Convert`CommonDump`templateBoxToDisplay[template]
BoxForm`TemplateBoxToDisplayBoxes[template]
```

> RowBox[{TemplateSlotSequence[1]}]
>
> RowBox[{"x", "y"}]

Note that the latter function produces acceptable boxes. I don't know why [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) uses its own custom function to convert [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) objects. So, a simple fix is to redefine `` System`Convert`CommonDump`templateBoxToDisplay ``:

```
System`Convert`CommonDump`templateBoxToDisplay = BoxForm`TemplateBoxToDisplayBoxes;
```

Now, [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) will work properly with any object whose format uses a [`TemplateSlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateSlotSequence) [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox):

```
ToString[BellY[a, b, {c, d}], TeXForm] //OutputForm
ToString[WignerD[{j, m1, m2}, θ], TeXForm] //OutputForm
ToString[Row[{a, b}, ","], TeXForm] //OutputForm
```

> $Y_{a,b}(c,d)$
>
> $D_{\operatorname{m1},\operatorname{m2}}^j(0,\theta ,0)$
>
> $a,b$

Comment: Thank you for such a deep analysis.  I am going to bookmark this for later re-reading.  One thing for now; you wrote: *I think TemplateBox offers both speed and memory advantages* – why would this be?

Answer (score 13):

The following works in Version 9.0.1.0 and Version 10.0.1.0

```
BoxForm`$UseTemplateSlotSequenceForRow = False; 
{x^a, Sqrt@b,  ArcSin[c]} // Row // TeXForm
(* x^a\sqrt{b}\sin^{-1}(c) *)
```

Comment: What on Earth is that?! +1 :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it is something that show up when I used my `whatOnEarthIs` function: ``whatOnEarthIs = 
 ToExpression["??*`*" ~~ ToString@# ~~ "*"] &; whatOnEarthIs@TemplateSlotSequence``:)

Comment: This seems to restore the old behavior therefore I am Accepting it.  Nevertheless I believe a bug remains in the current implementation as presumably `TemplateSlotSequence` is supposed to work and does not.

Answer (score 2):

```
TeXForm /@ {x^a, Sqrt@b, ArcSin[c]} // RowBox // DisplayForm
```

> $x^a\sqrt{b}\sin ^{-1}(c)$

Comment: This works for a single row, as does my own `StringJoin` method, but I still don't know how to use this for a larger expression that *contains* a `Row`.  If I use this method (or mine) to convert (only) the `Row` subexpressions, then apply `TeXForm` to the entire expression, the output is wrong.  I could *try* to do everything in pieces then assemble them but there are too many possibilities to make that robust.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about the following substitutions?

```
expr = Row@{x^a, Sqrt@b, ArcSin[c]};

expr /. Row@{x__} :> HoldForm@Times@x // TeXForm
```

> $ x^a \sqrt{b} \sin ^{-1}(c) $

```
expr2 = Row[{x^a, Sqrt@b, ArcSin[c]}, d];

expr2 /. Row[x_, y_] :> HoldForm@*Times @@ Riffle[x, y] // TeXForm
```

> $ x^a d \sqrt{b} d \sin ^{-1}(c) $

Comment: I haven't voted for this yet because I am unsure of `Times` being consistently formatted as a row.  Could you comment on that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard As I understand now, not always :( For example, it add parenthesis for `Row@{x+y,z}`. Nothing can compete with incredible @kguler's solution.