# TeXForm producing weird outputs

Tags: latex, format

When executing

```
TeXForm[ElementData[8, "ElectronConfigurationString"]]
```

the resulting `TeX` markup appears to include some internal box markup

```
\text{[He]}2\text{Superscript}[\text{s},2]2\text{Superscript}[\text{p},4]
```

> $\text{[He]}2\text{Superscript}[\text{s},2]2\text{Superscript}[\text{p},4]$

From that piece of code, I would expect something like $\text{[He]} 2s^{2} 2p^{4}$ to be produced.

I realize that something may be going on with *Mathematica*'s internal box-magic system, and I have tried converting it to other forms before passing it into `TeXForm`. This does not seem to do anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Version 9 and 10 (Windows 8 - 64 bit), you can use

```
BoxForm`$UseTemplateSlotSequenceForRow = False; 
ElementData[8, "ElectronConfigurationString"] /.  Superscript -> Power  // TeXForm
```

to get

```
\text{[He]}2\text{s}^22\text{p}^4
```

> $\text{[He]}2\text{s}^22\text{p}^4$

Related Q/A: [Incompatibility of Row and TeXForm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55363/125)