# How to avoid applying Cross to a single argument?

Tags: conditional

I am looking for the simplest way to avoid applying `Cross` to a single argument.

```
PrimeFactorization[x_] := Cross @@ (Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[x]);
Table[{n, PrimeFactorization[n]}, {n, 200, 250}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: What about `If`?

Comment: Down vote detected. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you already use `Cross` in a way that it's not meant to be used, you can also redefine it and assign a meaning to it when it has only a single argument:

```
Unprotect[Cross]; 
Cross[x_] := x;
```

A bit less severe: Define your own function.

```
cross[x__] := Cross[x];
cross[x_] := x;
```

Answer (score 10):

If it is only for displaying purposes you can use `Row`:

```
PrimeFactorization[x_] := Row[#, "\[Cross]"] & @ (Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[x])
```

Comment: This solution is not TeXForm friendly. Thank you!

Comment: @FriendlyGhost there is nothing about TeXForm in your question.

Comment: @FriendlyGhost, use ``BoxForm`$UseTemplateSlotSequenceForRow = False;`` before using `TeXForm` on expressions involving `Row`.(See [Incompatibility of Row and TeXForm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60224/125))

Answer (score 6):

You might define your own function cross, that calls Cross when the number of arguments is larger than 1:

```
cross=If[Length[{##}]>1, Cross[##], #]&;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any method to check the number of arguments instead of using your trick with `Length[{...}]`?

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution without defining new functions:

```
PrimeFactorization[x_] :=

 Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[x] /. y_ /; Length@y < 0 -> Cross @@ y
```

Answer (score 5):

For displaying purposes you can also use:

```
Times @@ Defer@*Power @@@ FactorInteger[10!]

CenterDot @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[10!]

Inactive[Times] @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[10!]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) This does not resolve the issue with numbers that are a power if a prime though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) in two ways:

1. temporarily re-define `Cross` so that  `Cross[t_] := t`:

```
PrimeFactorization[x_] :=  Block[{Cross}, Cross[t_] := t;
   Cross @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger @ x];

PrimeFactorization /@ {211, 222, 223} // TeXForm
```

> $\left\{211^1,2^1\times 3^1\times 37^1,223^1\right\}$

2. temporarily define `Sequence` as `Cross`:

```
PrimeFactorization2[x_] := Block[{Sequence = Cross},
    ## & @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger @ x];

PrimeFactorization2 /@ {211, 222, 223} // TeXForm
```

> $\left\{211^1,2^1\times 3^1\times 37^1,223^1\right\}$

Comment: I already up voted this answer! [The proof (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGUYT.png).