# Canonical form of list of Integers

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I get the canonical form of a list?
I tried

```
a = FactorInteger[Range[10, 11]]
b = Apply[Superscript, a, {2}]
CenterDot @@@ b
```

resulting in

```
{Superscript[2,1]\[CenterDot]Superscript[5,1], 
 CenterDot[Superscript[11,1]]}
```

Output for 10 is OK. But for case 11 the word "CenterDot" is in the output. How do I get rid of it? Or is there a more elegant way to "canonize" list or lists of integers?

Comment: `CenterDot @@@ b /. CenterDot[x_] :> x`?

Comment: Related link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180098/how-to-avoid-applying-cross-to-a-single-argument

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add the definition

```
CenterDot[u_] := u
```

then

```
a = FactorInteger[Range[1, 11]];
b = Apply[Superscript, a, {-2}];
CenterDot @@@ b
```

[image: factorizations]

Answer (score 6):

in 11.3 it works.

```
a = FactorInteger[Range[10, 11]]
b = Apply[Superscript, a, {2}]
f = If[Length@# == 1, #[[1]], CenterDot @@ #] &;
f /@ b
```

Comment: OK! Right! I got it! Thank you!