# Expressing an Edge List as a 0-1 Table with Headers

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Consider the edges

> `edges={S1040\[DirectedEdge]F283,S1197\[DirectedEdge]F243,S1197\[DirectedEdge]F245,S1863\[DirectedEdge]F243,S1863\[DirectedEdge]F245,S1863\[DirectedEdge]F283,S1863\[DirectedEdge]F244,S1863\[DirectedEdge]F246,S1863\[DirectedEdge]F247,S1863\[DirectedEdge]F280,S1863\[DirectedEdge]F281,S1863\[DirectedEdge]F282,S1863\[DirectedEdge]F284,S2174\[DirectedEdge]F243,S2174\[DirectedEdge]F280,S2174\[DirectedEdge]F281,S2174\[DirectedEdge]F284,S2325\[DirectedEdge]F247,S2340\[DirectedEdge]F245,S2344\[DirectedEdge]F282}`

How can I create an adjacency matrix from this graph in table form where the rows are the Fxxx nodes and the columns are the Syyyy nodes and both rows and columns are in increasing order. For example, row 1 is F243, row 2 is F244, etc. Likewise column 1 is S1040, column 2 is S1197, etc.

[image]

Comment: Correction: I'm looking for an adjacency matrix of 0's and 1s in Table form with the row column headers described above:

Comment: Ah, then it is good luck that nobody wasted their time with this... You should edit your question in order to address this change of aim.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The term "incidence matrix" is used in several ways. It could indicate the edge/vertex incidence, which is what `IncidenceMatrix` is for. It could indicate the adjacency of nodes from the two partitions of a bipartite graph. This is what is asked here, but `IncidenceMatrix` doesn't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
edges2 = edges /. DirectedEdge -> UndirectedEdge;
v = VertexList[Graph[edges2]];
am = Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[Graph[edges2]]];
fromv = Sort[Union[edges2[[All, 1]]]];
tov = Sort[Union[edges2[[All, 2]]]];
TableForm[
 am[[Flatten[Position[v, #] & /@ tov], Flatten[Position[v, #] & /@ fromv]]], 
 TableHeadings -> {tov, fromv}]
```

[image]

Comment: what is "v" in the above code for TableForm?

Comment: @PRG My bad, forgot to copy that line. Fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Fantastic!! ... Many thanks MelaGo

Answer (score 2):

This requires Szabolcs's package [`"IGraphM`"`](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM).

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
G = Graph[edges];
TableForm[
 IGBipartiteIncidenceMatrix[G],
 TableHeadings -> IGBipartitePartitions[G]
]
```

[image]

This code relies on `IGBipartiteIncidenceMatrix` using the same ordering and partitioning that is returned by `IGBipartitePartitions`.

It is possible to specify your own partitions (and ordering) in `IGBipartiteIncidenceMatrix`:

```
parts = Sort /@ IGBipartitePartitions[g, F243]
(* {{F243, F244, F245, F246, F247, F280, F281, F282, F283, F284}, 
    {S1040, S1197, S1863, S2174, S2325, S2340, S2344}} *)

MatrixForm[
 IGBipartiteIncidenceMatrix[g, parts],
 TableHeadings -> parts
]
```

[image]

Here we used the second argument of `IGBipartitePartitions` to indicate that the first partition should be the one containing `F243`. Then we sorted the vertices in each partition. Finally, we used the partition specification with `IGBipartiteIncidenceMatrix`.

Comment: Can you order the columns starting with F243?

Comment: Yes. And you also can, e.g. with `Ordering`.

Comment: wonderful...thank you very much Henrik ... prg

Comment: @PRG Yes, use the second argument of `IGBipartiteIncidenceMatrix` to indicate the specific ordering you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
v = Transpose[List @@@ edges];
{sources, sinks} = Union /@ v;
indices = Flatten[MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, #] & /@ {sources, sinks}];
sa = Transpose @ SparseArray[Transpose[v /. indices ] -> 1];
grid = Prepend[Join[List /@ sinks, sa, 2], Prepend[sources, ""]];
Grid[grid, Dividers -> {{2 -> True}, {2 -> True}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ran into trouble with TeXForm; it was unable to build the array and then table.

Comment: @PRG, it is probably related to [this issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55363/125). Try using ``BoxForm`$UseTemplateSlotSequenceForRow = False;`` before you call `TeXForm`

Comment: Still got an error:

Comment: \begin{array}{c|cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
   }
 \text{} & \text{S1016} & \text{S1031} & \text{S1047} & \text{S1064} & \text{S1067} & \text{S1084} & \text{S1113} &

Comment: @PRG, that is what `TeXForm` produces. I use `TeXForm` only  to generate an expression for posing on this page (as an alternative to positing an image of the output produced by `Grid[...]`). I deleted that part to avoid possible confusion.

Comment: wonderful, very creative! ... many thanks ... prg